# How to install Eclipse and open APK on eclipse?

Tags: android

Is there any way to open APK on Eclipse ?

Comment: an apk is not source. you can't just 'open it in eclipse'. There is lot's of interesting things you could do with an apk, also things like reverse engineering etc, but your short question does not invite to any meaningfull discussion about that.

Comment: You need to be more detailed with your question. Are you trying to open an apk in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can open .apk file like archive in your file manager.

Comment: I want to decompile Settings.apk and I want to change a thing in string.xml... I tried to decompile it using APK Tool... That is decompiled without error but after editing string.xml I tried to compile it but I get error